# Webpack 4 treeshaking vs devDependencies

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Since Webpack 4 supports tree-shaking, does it still matter if we put dependencies in `dependencies` or in `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file?

If tree shaking works as it is meant to, then all lint, flow, testing and tooling packages would get shaken off. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will remove unneeded code when creating bundle file. But if you want to reuse your code, or publish to npm, you should care about `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)