# Why does Electron need to be saved as a developer dependency?

Tags: javascript, electron, package.json, commonjs

As per the official website, the correct way to save electron files is:

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

Electron is actually required for running the app (quite literally: `require()`) and this goes against the [top voted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies). So why do we make this exception, if this is even one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The fact that you `require` a package is irrelevant to whether it should be considered a dependency or a devDependency (in the npm sense). E.g. many projects use webpack API (i.e. `const webpack = require('webpack')`) but list it as a devDependency.

The reason is also explained in the post you link to: when you `publish` your package, if the consumer project needs other packages to use yours, then these must be listed as `dependencies`.

If your package uses some modules only for build, test, or bundles them into a dist file (i.e. what will be used by the consumer project), then those modules should not be mentioned in `dependencies`. We still list them in `devDependencies` for development.

Now in the case of an electron app, there is little chance you will consume your app as a node module of a consumer project, therefore the above convention is not really relevant.

Furthermore, we fall in the case where the `electron` package is bundled as part of the built output. There is no need for your user to get `electron` from npm to use your built app. Therefore it matches well the definition of a devDependency.

That being said, IIRC some electron packagers bundle your `dependencies` into the built app, so you still need some rigour in filling this list.

Comment: Can we say that if your project will not be used by other projects as a module, there is no difference between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.?
Most of the time we develop some server, website etc. which will not be used as a module, so most of the time `devDependencies` and  `dependencies`  are same.

Comment: when i try to use `electron-builder` to create an executable, why do i get the following error: `"electron" is only allowed in "devDependencies" stackoverflow electron builder`

Comment: Hi @oldboy, i would guess you might be in the case described in the last paragraph of above answer, i.e. your packager tries to include your dependencies into your bundle, and fails to handle electron when it is in that list (it very probably knows how to handle it when omitted). Feel free to open a new question with details of your specific issue.

Comment: i figured it out. i simple moved it to dev dependencies, but i was under the impression that `electron` is an actual dependency, which is why it still doesnt make sense to me? anyways, now im running into another issue, and i have posted a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60143077/7543162)  .can you take a look if u dont mind?

Answer (score 3):

Cause those binary won't being used when you actually packaging into installer. Most of installer / packager for electron will build package with electron binaries, instead of using dependencies.

Comment: Does that mean the lines with `require('electron')` get transpiled into something else? Or that the packager embeds `electron`?