# Does "npm install electron" also downloads chromium?

Tags: node.js, proxy, electron

I'm trying to start the development of an electronJS app at my company, but I'm having a lot of trouble to install the framework by the command line "npm install electron". I have consulted the TI and our guess is that when running this the npm command, it tries to download chromium or other executables files and because of that our company proxy blocks the downloads of these files. I have installed chromium using a different way that is permitted by the proxy, so having chromium installed is not a problem. So summarizing I have two questions?

- Is chromium really downloaded with "npm install electron"?
- Is there any way I can install electronJS not using "npm install electron" or without downloading chromium?

I hope you can help me,
thanks

Note: I can't download any source code from github too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ElectronJS comes with Chromium. The application windows you see are Chromium instances.

It's also stated on their [web page](https://www.electronjs.org/) under "Web Technologies".

> Electron uses Chromium and Node.js so you can build your app with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Another place from which you can get it that they've provided on their GitHub page is [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/gh/electron/electron/tree/master), but the website seems to require registration.

**Tip**: when you're installing ElectronJS, I recommend doing it as stated by the official guide -> `npm install electron --save-dev` and **not just** `npm install electron`. As to why, you can read the reason [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803207/why-does-electron-need-to-be-saved-as-a-developer-dependency).

Another alternative is to download everything properly from somewhere else, e.g. your home, neighbour, café, etc., onto a USB Flash Drive and then when you get to your work place, have the IT department check the USB - once it's confirmed that it's safe, copy it to your work computer (make sure to consult with the apropriate department if you can do that).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll try to download from CirleCI, but I'm not sure I'll be able to download it from there either. About the other alternative, all USB ports are blocked as a security measure so it would not work. Thank you anyway!