# Ember package.json: dependencies vs devDependencies

Tags: ember.js, npm, package, npm-install

What is the difference of having the packages under the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in the package.json?

How does that impact in the final build?

Sounds quite simple, but I don't have it clear to which packages to put in each section. Even similar addon's documentations vary as well, some say to use `--save` and others `--save-dev`, which confuses me.

Answer (score 12):

In an ember app all your dependencies will go under `devDependencies` since you build the app via the ember cli and you do not include the app in another project.

For addons the story is a bit different, if your addon exposes any functionality from a package then that package has to be under `dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your `package.json` file and you will see two types of dependencies. One is called `devDependencies`(usually modules needed for local development) and one is called `dependencies` (dependencies used in production or that are integral to the given project). The `--save` flag adds your dependencies to the `dependencies` object of your `package.json` file and `--save-dev` adds your dependencies to the `devDependencies`. They're separated for convenience.

Edit:
This question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies), but the tldr; is, **it doesn't affect your production build**. Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I understand what the options do. I edited my question to be more clear.