# Should I bother resolving npm peer dependencies myself?

Tags: npm, dependencies, peer-dependencies

I seem to have gone down a rabbit hole with this. While I'm using webpack as an example, I'm looking for an answer that isn't specific to webpack. Ideally, I'd like to resolve these, but should I even bother?

I have an application whose dependencies have peer dependencies of various versions of webpack. When I run `npm install`, this is what I see (new lines added for clarity):

```
npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN file-loader@1.1.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@2.29.0 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN css-loader@1.0.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN schema-utils@0.4.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN sw-precache-webpack-plugin@0.11.4 requires a peer of webpack@^1 ||^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-beta || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 ||^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.9.4 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN webpack-manifest-plugin@1.3.2 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 ||3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I tried to install all the various versions, but wasn't sure how. In my package.json, the entry for webpack just kept updating to the last installed. When I hit `webpack@3.12.0`, the number of dependencies went down to:

```
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/googlemaps@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/markerclustererplus@^2.1.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/react@^15.0.0 ||^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN css-loader@1.0.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN schema-utils@0.4.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So, it seems that 3.12.0 meets the needs of most of my dependencies, but there are still some that are fussing. Ugh.

I tried putting things like `"webpack": "^3.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0"` into my package.json but that didn't really do anything. Maybe I need to add them all?

---

I've looked at many of the answers here, but a lot of them are Angular specific or just say "upgrade to npm >= 3". Ideally, I'm looking for a way to get these warnings to go away in any situation where many dependencies require different versions of another dependency.

This answer seems to get really close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/2800116

I tried `npm install --production`, to no avail.

Many answers here ask how to fix this hell but are not yet answered:
[npm started requestion manual install of peer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50581080/2800116)

My question is, **should I even bother with getting these to resolve?** It doesn't make the application break or anything, but it's just really annoying seeing these. I'm worried it'll create a "boy who cried wolf" situation where I'll just treat them as noise and miss things that could be important. *Sometimes even adding one of these peers adds MORE unmet peer dependencies.* Good grief!