# Reactjs Project installation issue

Tags: reactjs, github

I have cloned a react js project from Github to my local,

After giving 'npm start' i am getting the below error

**./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles' in 'C:\Users\Goodwork\desktop\xxxxxxxxxxx\src'**

Answer (score 1):

After cloning do npm install to download dependencies. run below command.

```
npm install
```

then run project

```
npm start
```

NOTE: if your package.json don't have `@material-ui/core` in dependencies list then  you may have to install it.

run this command.

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

Comment: @material-ui/core is there in my package.json also in the dev-depencies the following things are there should i want to install those files manually?   "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^3.4.8",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.8",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.4.8",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.4.8",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0"
  }

Comment: if you run `npm install` this will download all dependencies no need to download manually, are you running `npm install` within the same directory ?

Comment: There is a difference between dependencies and dev-dependencies right?? dev dependencies we should install by manually am I right??? if wrong, please correct

Comment: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ui-config/themes' in 'C:\Users\Goodwork\desktop\mihy-ui-framework\src'  i am getting like this

Comment: npm istall should install dev dependencies too,  check this ans -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies

Comment: Just do npm install this will install Dev dependencies as well as dependencies

Comment: Please share your code If you are getting issues when you do npm start otherwise it’s difficult to find root cause for your issues