# Should I install all the peer-dependencies manually to remove npm warnings?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

I installed via `npm` several angular packages, and I have this warning:

```
@angular/compiler-cli@7.2.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1.1 <3.3 
                                                                    but none is installed. 
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

a) What is the difference between peer- and just dependency?
b) What should I install now to fix the warning ?

I mean, suppose I install a package "P" I know, but this P needs X, Y and Z. Should I install them manually? It does not seem very cool...

Actually, I installed `Angular`, but `Angular` needs `compiler-clr` and the latest needs `typescript`.

When I saw this warning, I installed `npm install typescript` it installed me the version `typescript@3.3.3`, but this *** `compiler-clr` needs typescript@`<3.3`, what should I do now?

Should I analyse what version of typescript were out before `3.3`, and so on, for all the warnings of this type?

Comment: You could always install a specific version of typescript (e.g. `npm install typescript@~3.2.0`)

Comment: @Sustain, I don't know what version to install. maybe there are 3.2.9, or 3.2.7 before the 3.3. And why should I do it? Imagine I have hundreds of warnings like this. Need I analyse all the dependencies history to just install my angular and start developing my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a) <strike>A peer dependency of another dependency means that the former *can be installed alongside the latter*, while a dependency of another dependency *installs the former with the latter* without requiring you to do anything.</strike>

Check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies) for full info on the difference between `peerDependencies` and `dependencies`.

---

b) The [`@angular/compiler-cli`](https://npmjs.com/package/@angular/compiler-cli) ([GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/7.2.x/packages/compiler-cli)) package has a peer dependency of `typescript` from versions `3.1.1` to below `3.3.x`.

I suggest that you run `npm i -D typescript@~3.2.0` in your project's root to install `v3.2.x` in the `minor` semver (semantic versioner) range (check out [NPM's semver guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) for more info).

The `npm i -D typescript@~3.2.0` command does the following:

- `i` indicates that you're installing a package.
- The `-D` flag indicates that you're installing a package and adding it to the `devDependencies` object in your `package.json`
- `typescript@~3.2.0` indicates that you want to install the [`typescript`](https://npmjs.com/package/typescript) package in the version range of `3.2.x`, where `x` is a number.

  - `@~x.x.x` indicates that you want to install

    > *"Approximately equivalent to [the] version [specified (x.x.x in this case)]"* - [npm-package.json | npm Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

---

If you still have any questions or if you don't understand a thing, please comment with your queries on this answer. I'll try to help by responding as soon as possible. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: thanks, but you complicates a little bit the point a) I'd talk rather about a peer dependency PD vs dependency D of a package P. You say the difference is PD *can be* installed, but the D *is* installed... thinking like this, D also *can* be installed, and you don't say PD *is not* installed... and what is the logic PD should exist?

Comment: also, I don't understand why `angular` *does* install `compiler-cli`, but *does not* install `typescript` if it needs both of them?

Comment: For the second question, `ng new <project-name>` automatically adds the `typescript` dependency to your `package.json`, which is automatically installed.

Comment: i ran this npm i -D typescript@~3.2.0
but next time i run npm update, i still get the same message. Not sure why