# Need validation of my understanding of dev-dependencies and dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, package.json

I am a beginner (~15 days into learning web-development) and I am currently learning React among other things and I am sorry if this sounds too trivial.

I am trying to understand the difference between devDependencies and dependencies and the correct usage of the same.

I have tried to figure it out from the docs and stackoverflow questions but I am not a 100% sure if I have this right. So kindly review my understanding as of now and let me know if I have this right so far.

**Definition**

- dependencies: only the packages which are finally going to be used by the production build. These will be there in the final package.json file.
- devDepndencies: the packages which eases my development efforts and finally will not be used by the product / application. These will not be included in the package.json folder of the final build.

**Importance of correct usage**

Fairly important as correctly excluding devDependencies from dependencies can make the app lighter. At the same time, incorrectly excluding required dependencies will cause my app to break.

**Practical example**

In the package.json file created during my tutorial, I had the following packages and I am mentioning the type of dependency that the package should have according to my current understanding. Please let me know if I am erring somewhere:

- babel-cli : devDependency
- babel-core: devDependency
- babel-loader: devDependency
- babel-plugin-transform-class-properties: devDependency
- babel-preset-env: devDependency
- babel-preset-react: devDependency
- css-loader: devDependency
- node-sass: dependency
- react: dependency
- react-dom: dependency
- react-modal: dependency
- sass-loader: dependency
- style-loader: dependency
- validator: dependency
- webpack: dev-dependency
- webpack-dev-server: dev-dependency

Please let me know if I have any of these wrong

Comment: It's more of a run-time vs dev-time distinction.  I think most of those things are devDependencies because you don't need `node-sass` running whenever you are serving your app.  Webpack will put together a `dist` folder and you can hand that over to whatever static server you need.  That static server would likely be a dependency.  However, I wouldn't get too bogged down over the distinction.  You're optimizing prematurely rather than just developing.

Comment: I wrote an answer on another question that was confused about the distinction here: [Can you import a `devDependency` in your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55068767/691711)

Comment: @zero298: Thanks for your response. I am not developing at the moment, just learning the concepts. But I appreciate your concern that I may be overthinking this and will probably figure this out as I go deeper into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devDependencies` are the module dependencies which are only required during the **active development** of your web application. For example, when you're coding new features into your web application. A lot of `devDependencies` will make development easier on your end and can provide functionality such as linting, bundling, transpiling, etc...

In contrast, regular `dependencies` are the modules which are **necessary during the runtime** of your web application. I.e. these are the necessary dependencies for your web application to work correctly when other users want to interact with your web application.

**Note**: By module I mean the underlying code from the library which you're leveraging. A more complete definition can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules).

Your concerns about including more code than necessary for your production bundle are valid, and I would recommend reading more about the [Cost of JavaScript](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/the-cost-of-javascript-in-2018-7d8950fbb5d4). However, in the beginning I would encourage one to first get a working code base, and to keep iterating and improving your code as your skillset grows. Improving performance along the way.

Lastly, some common type of `devdependencies` include libraries for testing your code base, building, minifying, bundling, transpiling, and linting your code as well.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will check these out.

Comment: Please considering accepting my answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 2):

devDependencies are dependencies only required within your development environment or that are required for you to build your UI, for example **nodemon** is a dev dependency because you'll never run your application with it.

One of the advantages of splitting up your devDependencies from your normal dependencies is a smaller docker image size when building your final layer.

For example, in my dockerfile I'll run a suite of tests and also build the UI which requires an npm install but when building the final image that is going to actually run I will simply copy over the built UI files via docker then I'll run an npm install --production so that my devDependencies won't install and bloat my node_modules folder.

Hope this helps.