# How to use npm package dependency

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, npm-scripts

I am learning to create npm packages by creating a session check function `sessionFn` that will popup a modal 1 minute before the session expires.

The function works as expected on the main app (a nuxtJS app) but when I make use it as an npm module I have to pass `moment` as an argument even though `moment` is listed as a dependency and is imported on the module.

I am missing something, why is my module not picking up moment? I want to use the module like `sessionFn(this, to.path);` instead of `sessionFn(this, to.path, moment);` moment is undefined when I don't pass it

***Package files***

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "hello-stratech",
  "version": "1.0.17",
  "description": "Hello Stratech",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "npm",
    "hello",
    "stratech"
  ],
  "author": "Simo Mafuxwana",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.2"
  }
}
```

**index.js (main js file)**

```js
import moment from "moment";

module.exports = {
  greeting(name) {
    alert("Hello.. " + name);
  },
  department(dev) {
    ...
  },
  sessionFn(context) {
    const exp = context.$store.state.session.exp;
    let userSystemTime = new Date();
        userSystemTime = moment.utc(userSystemTime)

    const diff = moment(userSystemTime).diff(moment(exp), 'minutes');
    if (diff = 1) {
      // open modal
    }
  }
}
```

***Usage***

This is how I use the package in the main app

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import { sessionFn } from "hello-stratech";

export default {
  ...
  watch: {
    $route(to) {
      sessionFn(this, to.path, moment);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to import and pass moment into your function since you are importing it in your function file. You are not even using the passed argument in your function. So you can just safely dont pass it. You are also not using  second argument that u pass `to.path`, so u can omit it too.

As a suggestion you should install and use eslint, which will catch such things. You can setup a nuxt project with eslint using [create nuxt app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app) for example.

There is also a bug in esm 3.21-3.22 that prevent commonjs and es6 imports work together https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/773 . That should be fixed when a new esm will be released

Comment: `to,path` is used. The part of the code where it is used is irrelevant to the question hence it is not in the code snippet

Comment: *You dont need to import and pass moment into your function since you are importing it in your function file* - Like I said, when I use `sessionFn(this, to.path)` moment is undefined, I have to pass it `sessionFn(this, to.path, moment);` when calling the function for moment to be picked up

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana you are mixing cjs and es6 imports, there is bug in esm that break such usage, I guess it's your case. Change module.exports to es6 and try

Comment: It was that. I changed the import to `const moment = require("moment");` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana i have updated answer with reference to that esm bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making `moment` as devDependancy through `npm i moment --save-dev` instead of dependency.

That way moment will only be needed when the package is development (means when you are developing the project) but not when it is used.

Hope it fixes your issue

[for more depth knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)