# npm install - does a package need to be in both peerDependencies and dependencies?

Tags: npm, package.json

Would someone please tell me if am or am not suppose to put a package into both areas.

For example if I have in dependencies '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw...' and it has a peer dependency of 'leaflet-draw...' am I to place the leaflet-draw into the peerDependencies as well as the dependencies area?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/12032180) is great explanation about dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Answer (score 2):

I had this question as well and I think the answer is **yes**. I had conflicts with minor versions of rxjs (lots of type errors):

```
A depends on rxjs
A depends on B

B depends on rxjs
```

This would often result in two slightly different versions of rxjs being installed. So I tried this:

```
A depends on rxjs
A depends on B

B peer depends on rxjs
```

But when running tests etc for component B it was complaining that rxjs wasn't installed, so now I have:

```
A depends on rxjs
A depends on B

B depends on rxjs
B peer depends on rxjs
```

Works so far. The weird thing was that the version specification for rxjs in both projects would have allowed the same (latest) version of the library to be installed but npm/yarn still ended up installing two different copies.