# Are devDependencies installed with `npm install -g my-package`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies), but I'm not sure to understand the answers, and it seems it does not answer this particular case. So I prefer to ask this as a specific question:

Are `devDependencies` installed with `npm install -g my-package`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **devDependencies** are not included when you are installing a package (whether it's your own package or other packages).

Development dependencies are meant only for local development purpose which contains testing framework, documentation libraries and other, which is not required for the consumers who intended to consume /install/ use the packages.

So whenever you install a package using `npm -i <package-name>` or `npm -i -g <package-name>`  it only installs the **dependencies** not devDependencies. Check out this [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies)  for more info

Answer (score 1):

If `my-package` is a npm package that exist in npm registry - it will be installed globally without devDependencies.

The only difference `-g` makes in this situation is `my-package` would be installed globally in the machine instead of to local `node_modules` folder.