# Do we really need to strip packages from devDependencies in the name of performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, npm, dependencies

We all know, in most of the cases, packages listed under `devDependencies` won't make it into your build. So why do we strip them away in the name of performance?

E.g. I see many posts on Moment.js being replaced with another lightweight alternative, even if Moment.js is in `devDependencies`. How does it impact, considering all the frameworks (Ember, React, Vue and Angular)?

Comment: Are you asking about removing unused dependencies? How bundling and tree shaking works? Why people choose to not use Moment.js? If you're trying to reduce your own bundle size, have you observed any impact of these changes on your outputs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: No, my question is -- why people replace devDependencies in `package.json` in the name of performance?. This is not about unused, or bundling or any mechanisms. I want to get the reason behind the decisions.

unused packages should be removed, but am not asking about that

Answer (score 0):

`devDependencies` *do not* exclude the possibility that the dependency is required to make a bundle during build time --they are within the bundle that webpack generates for a website-- but not required by the package/system that installs it for production: i.e. the server-package that installs the app-package.

For example: your package `app` builds `moment.js` into its distribution bundle. When you then install package `app` as a dependency in a separate `server`, it  does not need to install `moment.js`, because it is already bundled within the `app`'s dist - so you explicitly put `moment.js` as a devDependency in `app`'s package.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a broad term. To some people, performance is only about production code. To others, performance of the *build system* matters. Removing unused `devDependencies` reduces build time and space, since `npm` needs to do less work.