# Difference between Dev Dependencies and Dependencies specifically in Cypress.io

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, package.json

Most of my plugins are installed as Dev Dependencies in package.json.
https://medium.com/@dylanavery720/npmmmm-1-dev-dependencies-dependencies-8931c2583b0c

But I still don't quite understand why and what would go in dependency vs dev dependency.
If I was modifying the cypress core would I install as a dependency? OR if I had a real app mixed (example Node + React) mixed with the same package.json?

Comment: Are both your cypress and tests and react application in the same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very good explanation about dependencies:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/9947826

Cypress is a testing tool and will not be required in a production environment. Therefore, it should be installed as a devDependency as stated in Cypress doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Cypress but Dev Dependencies are simply just dependencies that are only included in development mode. That is, when the environment variable `NODE_ENV` is set to `development`.

It is used for packages that are only intended to assist with debugging, and therefore should not be included in a finished production build.