# Errors importing d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js

I am new to d3 and am trying to create a line graph. I can't seem to properly import it, however, I get this error. I am using EmberJS, but I don't know if that is relevant.

```
Could not find module `d3` imported from 'filepath'.
```

This is my file:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

d3.json('URL');

export default class ComponentName extends Component {
}
```

I have done `npm install` and `npm ci` numerous times, and these relevant modules are in my `package.json`

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/d3": "^5.16.3",
        "d3": "^6.2.0",
    }
```

Other modules I have installed that didn't seem too relevant:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ember/optional-features": "^2.0.0",
        "@glimmer/component": "^1.0.1",
        "@glimmer/tracking": "^1.0.1",
        "@types/ember": "^3.16.1",
        "@types/ember-qunit": "^3.4.12",
        "@types/ember-resolver": "^5.0.10",
        "@types/ember-test-helpers": "^1.0.4",
        "@types/ember-testing-helpers": "0.0.3",
        "@types/ember__array": "3.0.4",
        "@types/ember__test-helpers": "^1.7.3",
        "@types/qunit": "^2.9.5",
        "@types/rsvp": "^4.0.2",
        "@types/sinon": "^7.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.11.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.11.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
        "ember-ajax": "^3.1.0",
        "ember-auto-import": "^1.6.0",
        "ember-cli": "~3.21.2",
        "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.2.0",
        "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.3",
        "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^2.0.2",
        "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
        "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
        "ember-cli-terser": "^4.0.0",
        "ember-cli-typescript-blueprints": "^3.0.0",
        "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
        "ember-disable-prototype-extensions": "^1.1.3",
        "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.1",
        "ember-load-initializers": "^2.1.1",
        "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
        "ember-qunit": "^4.6.0",
        "ember-resolver": "^8.0.2",
        "ember-sinon": "^4.0.0",
        "ember-sinon-qunit": "^3.4.0",
        "ember-source": "~3.21.1",
        "ember-source-channel-url": "^3.0.0",
        "ember-template-lint": "^2.11.0",
        "ember-try": "^1.4.0",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ember": "^8.13.0",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
        "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2",
        "qunit-dom": "^1.4.0",
        "semantic-release": "^15.13.16",
        "sinon": "^7.2.2",
        "typescript": "^4.0.3"
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "extends": "some-custom-config",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "module": "es6",
      "paths": {
        "*": [
          "types/*"
        ]
      }
    },
    "include": [
      "app/**/*",
      "addon/**/*",
      "tests/**/*",
      "types/**/*",
      "test-support/**/*",
      "addon-test-support/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `d3` is added as a devDependency instead of as a dependency. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/5015356) on the differences

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I tried changing it to a regular dependency instead of a devDependency and the error persists.

Comment: Is the package present in `node-modules/`?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot yes, it is

Comment: is `ember-auto-import` installed?

Comment: @Lux yes, that is installed as well.

Comment: Does it work to `import { json } from "d3-fetch"` instead?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot just tried changing my import to that, and changing method from `d3.json('url')` to `json('url')`. I still get an error, this time `Could not find module 'd3-fetch'`. I verified d3-fetch exists in my `/node_modules` as well.

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I added my tsconfig, albeit I have removed the majority of the paths (the information is somewhat private, unfortunately). If you believe the issue lies in the paths, let me know so that I can look at it further.

Comment: Try adding `"rootDirs": ["../node_modules"],`. that might help ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs))

Comment: @RubenHelsloot didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: And do any other packages work? momentjs, for example?

Comment: can you try adding `"d3-force": "^2.0.1",` to your `package.json` and then do `import { forceCollide } from 'd3-force';`? Thats 1:1 from a real project.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a module called 'ember-d3' is needed to use d3 with ember.