# Transitive npm devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

We know [how the dependencies work in NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies?rq=1). My question is, how can I create a common-library that provides *dev* dependencies to multiple other components?

Let's say I have a microservice architecture where all the components use *mocha* and *nyc* for running the tests.

I don't want to go into each separate component to add them, but to manage this "testing framework" from one central library in `devDependencies` - however since they are not transitive, they are not installed. I cannot also put them in `dependencies` because they are not relevant in production mode...

Is it possible in NPM?

Answer (score 1):

I've Searched for the same but sadly, the response is :
**no, this isn't possible in NPM**.

### Workaround

Adding them directly inside the `peerDependencies` list and counting on the three shaking to make it work.

### Feature-request

https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/553