# Where goes React / Next.js packages to dependencies or devDependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am curious how to do it correctly, I see many of those package can be either "dependencies" or "devDependencies". Does it really matter how do I install them?

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^11.1.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@styled-system/css": "^5.1.5",
    "@swan-bitcoin/xpub-lib": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.8",
    "@types/next": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-date-range": "^1.1.8",
    "@types/react-ga": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/react-qr-reader": "^2.1.3",
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "accounting-js": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bip32": "^2.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "detect-browser-language": "^0.0.2",
    "konva": "^7.2.5",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "next": "10.0.5",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^7.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.13.8",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-bitcoin-qr": "^0.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-country-region-selector": "^3.0.2",
    "react-countup": "^5.2.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-konva": "^17.0.2-0",
    "react-leaf-carousel": "^2.0.3",
    "react-messenger-customer-chat": "^0.8.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^1.0.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.1",
    "react-parallax": "^3.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-qr-reader": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.11",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.42.1",
    "sharp": "^0.28.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-icons": "^10.38.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "styled-system-html": "^3.0.0",
    "use-image": "^1.0.8",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.21",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: React/Next.js go to dependencies because they will be used when app is live. Render , state etc. (a lot of function) will be handled by these. While dev dependecies are like testing libraries like Jest or mocha. Because it wouldn't be required when app is live