# Why is node-sass being built when I upgrade from npm6 to npm7?

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, npm-install, node-sass

My app uses sass, not node-sass. node-sass is nowhere in my package-lock.json.

I'm currently using npm 6 and everything is working fine and has been for years.

When I try to `npm install` with npm 7, it fails with the below error.

What's going on? Maybe node-sass is a dev dependency of something else and being built?

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path /Users/john/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonenbaf30/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! npm ERR! Building: /opt/local/bin/node /Users/john/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonenbaf30/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.3.6"' -I/Users/john/.node-gyp/14.18.3/include/node -I/Users/john/.node-gyp/14.18.3/src -I/Users/john/.node-gyp/14.18.3/deps/uv/include -I/Users/john/.node-gyp/14.18.3/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o ../src/libsass/src/eval.cpp
### above line repeated many times
npm ERR! npm ERR!
```

Comment: Are any of the packages that you use using `node-sass`?

Comment: By that do you mean, do they have it as a dependency? No, `node-sass` does not appear anywhere in package-lock.json.

Comment: As far as I understand, `node-sass` is the program that compiles sass. So I think you always need it: `npm install node-sass`

Comment: these are two separate projects which do mostly the same thing

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: There is node-sass and dart-sass. You should be using Dart-Sass per the SASS lang website

Comment: @JohnBachir it doesn't have to be in your `package.json`. It could be a dependency of a package that is in there though, and that would be listed in that package's `package.json`. The word "package" has lost all meaning now.

Comment: @Brad the `sass` package is indeed dart-sass

Comment: @Andy right, but note that I said package-lock.json

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a version of Node or npm that are not compatible with the version of `node-sass` that is being pulled. `node-sass` publishes [this table](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy) that shows the range of supported versions for any toolchain version. If one of your dependencies is pulling `node-sass`, you could force your desired version by explicitly specifying `node-sass` as a direct dependency. You could also consider upgrading Node or npm as an alternative.

Comment: thanks - my version is compatible. but the bigger question is... why is node-sass being built

Answer (score 1):

To see what would happen I tried `npm install --package-lock-only`, and it succeeded. I could then see the dependency tree. `node_modules/sass-loader` has `node-sass` as a peer dependency.

npm7 installs peer dependencies by default and doesn't allow getting into an ambiguous state. (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/168143 )

So, that's why this was happening. I don't know if I wasn't reading the stack trace well enough or if there is some other standard way for me to have figured out what had the dependencies. I'll leave this question without an accepted answer just in case someone has a smarter way to diagnose this sort of thing.