# What's the difference?? REACT vs REACT_PROJECT vs WEBPACK_REACT for storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

after 'npx sb init'

[menu list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhD4a.png)

I installed all of them and what I got is..

[file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4L0W.png)

I really don't know how/what they are different..
what's the point of 'react, react_prject,webpack_react' ??

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the Storybook file:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/lib/cli/src/project_types.ts
In REACT_PROJECT the react configured as peer dependency as for REACT it's dependency. WEBPACK_REACT contains react & webpack as dependencies.

The difference between them explained well here:
[What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

From the installation docs:

```
The command above will make the following changes to your local environment:

 Install the required dependencies.
 Setup the necessary scripts to run and build Storybook.
 Add the default Storybook configuration.
 Add some boilerplate stories to get you started.
```