# How to distribute dependencies in package.json?

Tags: node.js, react-native, frontend

So I'm building a Front End application based on React. There'll be different packages serving as libraries and exporting components. These components will then be imported into the **main** package and routed according to need.

Now for the package(s) serving as libraries; I'm trying to understand how to distribute the dependencies between `dependencies`, `devDependencies`, and `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` file.

Should I be putting everything in dev and peer? Or do things like lodash / babel etc. need to be put in dependencies? Any such best practices; or list of dependencies would be helpful

Comment: This can be helpful for you: [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Answer (score 1):

[About dependencies and devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file)

### Dependencies

> "dependencies": Packages required by your application in production.

In dependencies you put everything that is imported in your application or needed in some way in the final application, e.g: `react`, `axios` etc.

### devDependencies

> "devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local development and testing.

In devDependencies you put only things that are used to build your application, eg. `webpack`, `eslint` etc.

### peerDependencies

You can read about peerDependencies [here](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

You won't use them unless your project is a library.

Questions:

> Should I be putting everything in dev and peer?

No, it's safer to put everything in `dependencies` if you don't know where to put it.

> Or do things like lodash / babel etc. need to be put in dependencies?

No, `lodash` should be in `dependencies`, because, you are using it in your website. `babel` on the other hand is used only in built time, so it should be in `devDependencies`.