# Next.js 13 devDependencies?

Tags: next.js, dependencies, bundling-and-minification

I remember in Next.js 12, the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` are still following the rules from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/10930293). But now, when I type `pnpm create next-app`, all of the dependencies installed (no matter if they're only used for dev or both dev and prod) are all inside `dependencies`.

```json
// Next 12

  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }

// Next 13

  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.8",
    "eslint": "8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.2",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
```

Is Next.js 13 do the minification itself for me? Should I separate them manually, defying `create-next-app`'s recommendation? I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like a bug, they should still follow the format from Next.js 12.

Comment: I'm also curious about this. I recently had trouble deploying my NextJs app. It was complaining about missing @types/react and tailwind until I moved all deps from dev dependencies to dependencies.

Comment: @AndyOh this can't be right. Tailwind is not needed during production. It uses a compiler that just spits out CSS after it's done compiling. This never happens in real time in prod. Only during the build in dev.

Comment: same thing happened to me

Comment: Seems like this is fine. Answer here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43066#issuecomment-1319969015

Comment: This should be marked as an anti-pattern in the Next.js docs. In general, I still prefer to separate my dependencies.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @kelvin has mentioned in a commentary, one of the members of Vercel has [explicitly stated](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43066#issuecomment-1319969015):

> Hi, this is expected. Next.js is not relying on dependencies vs. devDependencies either if you host on platforms like Vercel or use output: "standalone".

So the proper answers to your questions are:

> Is Next.js 13 do the minification itself for me?

Yes it will minify for you and it seems that it doesn't rely on `devDependencies` in order to achieve it.

> Should I separate them manually, defying create-next-app's recommendation?

No, according to Balázs Orbán you shouldn't or, at least, you don't have to. But I think that as it is not required by next.js it is not forbidden also, because many of the [official examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) are still separating them.

Please note that, for react applications that don't use next.js (and also other kind of applications based on npm and yarn package managers) the separation between `dependencies` and `devDependencies` is still necessary.

**Note:** *Kelvin has already answered it. But as a commentary it was a little bit hidden. I'm posting it as an answer with some more explanation just to highlight the answers for those, like me, that get here by searching.*

Comment: You should boldface the `Please note that, for react applications that don't use next.js [parenthetical] that separation between dependencies and devDependencies` **is still necessary**.

Comment: @morganney, Although I could, I don't think I should. We're clearly talking about next.js. The question is about next.js. That paragraph is just a foot note, a courtesy reminder or a disambiguation note. I don't think that it should be highlighted in any way.

Answer (score 2):

this is probably a bug

should be this

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@next/font": "13.1.1",
  "next": "13.1.1",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "18.11.17",
  "@types/react": "18.0.26",
  "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
  "eslint": "8.30.0",
  "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
  "typescript": "4.9.4"
}
```

note that as of now `@next/font` also installed automatically

Answer (score 2):

It was true in the past but I just tried **create-next-app** today - and now the **dependencies** and **devDependencies** are listed separately.

This is from my `package.json` file:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.3"
 },
 
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3"
 }
```