# Issue during npm install and deploying on heroku

Tags: angular, npm, heroku, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting this error all time.

```
Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.0
       npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.9.3
       npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
       npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~4.9.3" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
       npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.8.4
       npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
       npm ERR!   peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.0
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
       npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.zQoom/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.zQoom/_logs/2022-11-19T21_40_57_670Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
```

I tried npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps,updating all libaries etc. but I cannot fix it. Can sb help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--legacy-peer-deps` is rarely the correct choice. Fixing the conflict is always better.

In this case, you have a direct dependency on TypeScript `~4.9.3` and a peer dependency of `~4.8.2` from `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. Those two version constraints are in conflict.

In general, you have two choices: downgrade your direct dependency or upgrade the dependency with the relevant peer dependency.

But in this case, it looks like you're already using the latest version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. TypeScript 4.9 is [only a few days old](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/), so it's not surprising that some of your dependencies aren't compatible with it yet.

I suggest you revise your direct TypeScript dependency to match your peer dependency: `~4.8.2`.

Comment: what is peer dependency

Comment: @RajaSekaran, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18875674/354577