# Next 14 devDependencies

Tags: next.js, dependencies

I want to understand why NextJS 14 installs most packages on devDependencies.. Are most packages on NextJS 14 just for testing. Wouldn't that cause some issues when moving to production.

I just want to understand why NextJS 14 installs most packages on devDependencies

Comment: does this help? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencie)