# Why use peer dependencies instead of regular after npm 7?

Tags: npm, dependency-management

Suppose we have the following situation. You are working on `cool-app` and depend on `react` and `cool-package`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.0.0",
  "cool-package": "^1.0.0"
}
```

You are unfortunately still on React 16 instead of 18. `cool-package` on the other hand has a peer dependency of React 18:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^18.0.0",
}
```

In npm versions 4, 5 and 6, if you try to `npm install` in `cool-app`, you will get a warning about an unmet peer dependency. This is because `cool-app` doesn't provide a version of `react` that meets the version requirements of `^18.0.0`.

If `cool-package` instead had a regular dependency (not a peer dependency) on `react` with a version requirement of `^18.0.0`, when you `npm install` in `cool-app`, a second version of `react` will be downloaded since the v16 of React that `cool-app` has can't meet the `^18.0.0` requirement of `cool-package`.

However, in npm v7 (and every version since ([1](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/1927876))), the behavior of peer dependencies has changed. If the peer dependency hasn't been met, instead of displaying a warning when you `npm install`, it will instead install the missing dependency, just like it would have done if regular dependencies were used instead of peer dependencies.

So in our example with `cool-app`, if we're using npm 7, `cool-app` will have two different versions of React: v16 and v18 even though `cool-library` uses a peer dependency.

Given this, I am unclear about what the differences are between regular and peer dependencies, and on how important these differences are in practice.

Context: [This](https://github.com/jsr-io/jsr/issues/332#issue-2207274429) is the conversation that lead to me having these questions.

Comment: The _purpose_ of peer dependencies hasn't changed. How they are _handled_ has changed slightly, for the better: if you're using React 16, then using a dependency that relies on a newer version being in place could fail spectacularly and you _should_ be told that very clearly when trying install it. That dependency declaring a _non_-peer dependency and pretending that's what will actually exist at runtime doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the peer dependency hasn't been met, instead of displaying a warning when you npm install, it will instead install the missing dependency,

This isn't what is says [here](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies):

> In previous versions of npm (4-6), peer dependencies conflicts presented a warning that versions were not compatible, but would still install dependencies without an error. **npm 7 will block installations if an upstream dependency conflict is present that cannot be automatically resolved**

And it's what I've experienced. If you have a dependency in your package.json whose version is unable to reconcile with a peerDependency of the dependency you're installing, it doesn't install that peerDependency, instead it fails to install the dependency, which is a much better behaviour, IMO.

> So in our example with cool-app, if we're using npm 7, cool-app will have two different versions of React: v16 and v18 even though cool-library uses a peer dependency.

This is incorrect. If `cool-app` has react `^16` installed and you try to install `cool-package` that has a dependency on react `^18` - it fails - it's an unresolvable conflict.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencie/22004559#22004559) you referenced you'll note the same:

> in version 7 peerDependencies are automatically installed **unless an upstream dependency conflict is present that cannot be automatically resolved**