# what does bundledDependencies do when publishing a package to npm registry? (when using "npm publish", not when using "npm pack")

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

In the npm documents, we read about `bundledDependencies`:

> This defines an array of package names that will be bundled when
>   publishing the package.

What is the meaning of publishing the package? I know that bundledDependencies are bundled in the tarball file after running `npm pack`. But is there any difference between bundledDependencies and normal dependencies when running `npm publish` and publishing the package to the npm registry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advantages of bundledDependencies over normal dependencies in npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207638/advantages-of-bundleddependencies-over-normal-dependencies-in-npm)

Comment: No, my question is about the effect of bundledDependancies on publishing the package to npm registry. (for example "npm publish"). thanks anyway.

Comment: `npm publish` essentially runs `npm pack` before publishing the package (`.tgz`) to the registry (see source code files; [publish.js](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/36682d4482cddee0acc55e8d75b3bee6e78fff37/lib/publish.js) and [pack.js](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/3e7ed30d6e9211e39bd93ec4e254cc5a2b159947/lib/pack.js)), so I think you've answered your own question, i.e. _"I know that bundledDependencies are bundled in the tarball file after running `npm pack`"_